# Adding a Next/Previous Button Image to a jQuery Slideshow

Tags: jquery, button, slideshow

I have a jquery slideshow i am building and i have the main slides rotating left and right automatically and thumbnails the right that you can click on to rotate the images as well.

i want to place an image of an arrow on both the left side and right side of the main slides, that when clicked, will rotate the slideshow in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start.  You'll need to keep a global variable of what the current image displayed is.  Then have a mapping between that variable and the image list in your database.

```
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#buttonLeft").click(function(){
         $("#image1").attr('src','http://scm-l3.technorati.com/11/05/04/33025/obama1.jpg?t=20110504183038');
    });

    $("#buttonRight").click(function(){
         $("#image1").attr('src','http://faculty.smu.edu/rblair/Bush.jpg');
    });

});

</script>

</head>
<body>

<button id="buttonLeft" type="button">&lt;==</button><button id="buttonRight" type="button">==&gt;</button>
<br /><br />
<img id="image1" src='http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo2w.png' />


</body>
</html>
```